# Using action hook to display a custom field in printed WooCommerce order details

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, printing, hook

In WooCommerce, I'm trying to use a custom field made with [Checkout Field Editor for WooCommerce](https://wordpress.org/plugins/woo-checkout-field-editor-pro/) plugin in the print order. We use [BizPrint Print Manager](https://wordpress.org/plugins/print-google-cloud-print-gcp-woocommerce/) plugin connected to BizSwoop print service to get them printed in our restaurant.

Here is the developer documentation for action hooks:
https://getbizprint.com/documentation/developer/#actions

I tried using the following code, but sadly it's not working:

```
add_action( 'Zprinttemplatesorder-htmlafterShippingDetails', 'afterShippingDetails', 10, 1 );

function afterShippingDetails( int $order_id  ): void {
    echo 'Sede de dónde sale el pedido ' . $order_id->billing_sede;
}
```

But if I hard code it into the html/php as follows:

```
<tr>
<td colspan="4"><?php _e('Sede de dónde sale el pedido :', 'Print-Google-Cloud-Print-GCP-WooCommerce'); ?>
<?= $order->billing_sede; ?></td>
</tr>
```

It will work...

Any help is appreciated.

EDIT 1:

I cant still get it to work, after reading some code Im trying the following one. I dont know if its correct

```
function sede_orden ( $order_id ) {
        $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
        echo '<h4>'.__('Sede de dónde sale el pedido: ').'</strong> ' . $order->get_billing_sede . '</h4>'; 
    }
add_action( 'Zprinttemplatesorder-htmlend', 'sede_orden', 10, 1 );
```

Comment: I made an edit on the main thread, I just cant get it to work. Any help is appreciated.